# Multivariate limit as $\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}$ goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate, for fixed $a, b∈ ℝ  $, the limit

$$\lim_\limits{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \to 0} \frac{ah_2 + bh_1}{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}}.$$

Multiplying by $\frac{\frac{1}{h_1h_2}}{\frac{1}{h_1h_2}}$ did not help me, and neither did writing the function in polar coordinates, because then we obtain

$$\lim_\limits{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \to 0} \frac{ah_2 + bh_1}{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}} = \lim_\limits{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \to 0} \sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \frac{a \sin(\arctan\left(\frac{h_2}{h_1}\right))+ b\cos(\arctan\left(\frac{h_2}{h_1}\right))}{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}}, 
$$
and I don't know what to do with the ratio $\frac{h_2}{h_1}$ since these seem to be able to take any value.

I want the limit to be $0$, but now I'm not so sure that is actually true.

Comment: Say that fraction is  $f(h_1,h_2)$. What are $f(h_1,0)$ and $f(0,h_2)$ (for $h_j>0$).

Comment: Yes, for those choices the limit is indeed $0$, but shouldn't it be zero _for all_ possible combinations?

Comment: Try letting $h= t (1,0)$ and compute the limit as $t \to 0$.

Comment: **Hint:** When someone trying to help asks you a question it will probably be more useful if you _answer_ the question! Tell me: If $h_1>0$ what is $f(h_1,0)$? (My **guess** is that you answered a different question instead because you thought the answer to my question was obvious. Yes, the question about what is $f(h_1,0)$ is totally triivial, but it seems pretty clear that you're getting it _wrong_...)

Comment: "You conveniently take the limits where..." No, I didn't take any limits at all; I left that to you. All I did was ask what $f(h_1,0)$ was.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Re-check your calculations, because those expressions are wrong. Also, division by zero is not defined!, so writing $h_2/0 = \infty$ is meaningless in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $h_{1}=0$ and $h_{2}>0$, the expression reduces to $\dfrac{ah_{2}}{h_{2}}=a$ while for $h_{1}>0$ and $h_{2}=0$, the expression reduces to $\dfrac{bh_{1}}{h_{1}}=b$, while for $h_{1}=2h_{2}>0$, the expression reduces to $\dfrac{(a+2b)h_{2}}{\sqrt{5}h_{2}}=\dfrac{a+2b}{\sqrt{5}}$, if the limit exists, it is necessary that $a=b=\dfrac{a+2b}{\sqrt{5}}$, this leads to $a=b=0$.

But we still need to check if $a=b=0$ the expression has limit or not, this is trivial since the whole expression is just zero.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are not simultaneously $0$ (because in that case, the limit is trivially $0$). WLOG, suppose that $a \neq 0$. Let $h_1 = 0$ (so, we are approaching along the $y$-axis). Then,
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ah_2 + b(0)}{\sqrt{(0)^2 + h_2^2}} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{ah_2}{\sqrt{h_2^2}} = \lim_{h \to 0} \left(a \cdot \dfrac{h_2}{|h_2|} \right)
\end{align}
The limit on the RHS does not exist since $a \neq 0$. Therefore, the original limit you asked about does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b $ are zero then the limit is clearly zero.

Suppose $(a,b) \neq 0$, pick $h $ such that $ah_1+bh_2 \neq 0$. Consider taking the limit
with $th$ as $t \to 0$.

We have $ { a t h_1 + b t h_2 \over \sqrt { (th_1)^2 + t (h_2)^2} } = {t  \over |t|}{ a h_1 + b h_2 \over \sqrt { h_1^2 + h_2^2} } $.

If we let $t=(-1)^n {1 \over n}$ we see that the above values alternates between
$\pm { a h_1 + b h_2 \over \sqrt { h_1^2 + h_2^2} } $, hence there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_\limits{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \to 0} \frac{ah_2 + bh_1}{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}} = \lim_\limits{r \to 0} \frac{ar\cdot cos(\theta) + br\cdot sin(\theta)}{r} = a\cdot cos(\theta) + b\cdot sin(\theta)$$

This limit depends on choice of $\theta$, so is undefined.